# Nmap can't find saved text file

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, save, nmap

I am learning to use nmap an zenmap for collage. I need to save the resoult to file. First i thought there is something wrong whit my code. Then I used cat and the file is saved ok. But i cant find it, they are not in my home folder, they are not in my data or anywhere else.

> nmap -oN somerandom.txt -sS -O 192.168.1.103

Plus where can i find /proc/net/arp directory in linux

Comment: Use the command line (use `pwd` to get your current directory, and perhaps `ls -l` then `find` to find some file). Try `ls -l /proc/net/arp`; BTW, folders do not really exist (Linux has *directories*).

Comment: thank you i will try to find where it is.

Comment: it was in /root that i cant acces. Can u tell me how can i acces if ? for the time being i moved all files to home. can u write this as an awser so i can give points to u ?

Answer (score 0):

> it was in /root that i cant acces. Can u tell me how can i acces if ?

Presumably you haven't access permissions for `/root` (one wouldn't have to guess if you provided the error message); you could switch to the user whom `/root` belongs to (usually `root`).